# cannot set Last-Modified/Etag header in .net web api on IIS7.5

Tags: http, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to set the lastmodified date/etag in the Web API response.

```
        response.Headers.ETag = new EntityTagHeaderValue("\"1\"");
        response.Content.Headers.LastModified = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
        return response;
```

However, it is not working if I host that IIS, but if I tried to debug that and hit the api host by visual studio vs2012 (when I try to debug), I am getting the value back.

Anyone has any suggestion on that? I think it has something to do with the configuration on IIS, but I cannot figure that out.

Response header while hitting API hosting from IIS7.5

```
Cache-Control →no-cache
Content-Length →2399
Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8
Date →Thu, 19 Dec 2013 07:03:18 GMT
Expires →-1
Pragma →no-cache
Server →Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version →4.0.30319
X-Powered-By →ASP.NET
```

Response header while hitting api hosting from vs2012 debug

```
Cache-Control →no-cache
Content-Length →2399
Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8
Date →Thu, 19 Dec 2013 07:07:22 GMT
Expires →-1
Last-Modified →Wed, 18 Dec 2013 07:07:22 GMT
Pragma →no-cache
Server →Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version →4.0.30319
X-Powered-By →ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles →=?UTF-8?B?QzpcU291cmNlXGFwbVxzcmNcc2VydmljZXNcV2Vic2VydmljZXNcQ0lTXGFwbVxwcm9wZXJ0eWRhdGFcYXV0b3N1Z2dlc3RcdjFcZnJlZXRleHQ=?=
```

Comment: This has to be an IIS configuration issue.  What HttpModules are installed in IIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i figured this out myself.

We need to enable the cache control in order to set those header in .net web api

```
    response.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue();
    response.Headers.CacheControl.Public = true;
```

I guess that is because those header are related to cache in http protocol that is why .net enforce that in the framework.